# Addons Not showing up in Toolbar (Blender 2.8 Alpha)

Tags: add-on

After installing the addons in the user preferences, they don't show up anywhere in blender 2.8 except from workspace addons tab in the properties and clicking it doesnt do anything. In user preferences next to the addons list, it also says that "Upgrade to 2.8x required". Does that mean that we can't use any addons in 2.8 unless they are upgraded for 2.8 builds?

Comment: Since the addon version check, need to update to `"blender" : (2, 80, 0)` in the `bl_info` dictionary to register an addon. Some basic changes like no more `scene.objects.[link, active]` break a lot of addons.  If you really  want to disable the check, find the file `2.80/modules/addon_utils.py` and edit the line `if mod.bl_info.get("blender", (0, 0, 0)) < (2, 80, 0):
` to `if True:`  (The addons may register, but be aware a lot of ops and panels will be broken)

Comment: whoops  that should be `if False:` above, to remove the check. Liking 2.8 too, albeit a little frustrating.

Comment: Oh i was struggling to get it work with If True.... Thank you :)

Comment: I got it working by doing this:

if mod.bl_info.get("blender", (0, 0, 0)) < (2, 80, 0):
Change to 
if mod.bl_info.get("blender", (0, 0, 0)) < (2, 79, 0):

Answer (score 3):

Blender 2.8 has yet to notify the add-on developers to make it compatible with 2.8.

If you see a message stating "Upgrade to 2.8x required" it means the addon was made for older versions of Blender 2.7x and does not work for newer versions.

Unfortunately there is very little you can do as a user to fix it.

Check the author website for an newer updated version, or ask the developer for an update. Most addons require small changes to adapt and can be easily updated.

If it is a commercial addon you payed for try contacting support for an update. It is often in the best interest of the owners to make it work in the latest release.

Otherwise roll up your sleeves, learn Python, and update the addon yourself by coding in the required changes in. Most addons require only small adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

The add-ons now appear on the opposite side menu bar. Where they used to show up on the (T) menu bar, they now show up as tabs beside the (N) menu bar.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Ok the addons are in the addons in the preferences in 2.80  the mesh 2 is there
But I am missing the measuremnts and the snap utils that used to show up in the T toolbar. Tool bar T is missing now.
Someone else must be scratching there head about why the addons are included with 2.80 but no person can find them to use them.